# How to VACUUM INTO in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with many rows that were added and removed over time. It's getting fairly large and sqlite doesn't free space when rows are deleted.

Need to run a manual `vacuum` to compact the database. I've been trying to run a vacuum but I can't get the command to work. The [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) doesn't explain much and doesn't give working examples.

How to `VACUUM INTO` in sqlite?

Comment: How have you been running it and what errors if any are you getting?

Comment: `VACUUM INTO` seems to be quite "new". With sqlite 3.22 (2018-01-22) I get the error `Error: near "INTO": syntax error`. With sqlite 3.31 (2020-01-27) it works

Comment: The `INTO` clause of `VACUUM` was added in 3.27 from February 2019. https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand your frustration, it took me a whole afternoon too the last time I had to run a VACUUM. The doc could certainly do a better job of explaining the parameters.

In sqlite 3:

```
VACUUM main INTO 'C:\\Users\\username\\PycharmProjects\\project\\dbcompacted.sqlite';
```

The default schema name is `main`. Existing schemas can be listed with `PRAGMA database_list;`.

This syntax is introduced in sqlite 3.15 (October 2016). In older versions the schema name is hardcoded to main, it cannot be passed as a parameter. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html

Depending on sqlite version, the schema parameter may be optional or may be ignored.

Specify an absolute path (and escape backslash characters for Windows). The current directory might be anything, depends how the database is opened and the query is executed. For me it kept failing with an error `unable to open database: dbcompacted.sqlite` when omitting the full path.

Answer (score -2):

```
Two simple steps for your targets.
```

At first initialize auto_vacuum property before any operations,
and then, after commited changes, execute VACUUM command.
Follow the sample code:

```
            import sqlite3 as db
            cnx = db.connect(dbfile, uri=True)
            cnx.execute("PRAGMA auto_vacuum = 1");
            # 
            # Do something with your db file
            #
            cnx.commit() #it is necessarily!
            cnx.execute("VACUUM")
            cnx.commit()
            cnx.close()
```